# Происхождение выражения

Tags: этимология

Задаю вопрос по другому: происхождение фразеологизма- ТОЧИТЬ ЛЯСЫ.

Comment: Можно было тот вопрос подкорректировать.

Comment: _Tata: ...происхождение фразеологизма- ТОЧИТЬ ЛЯСЫ._ === Прочтите комментарий к Вашему предыдущему вопросу: там есть ответ и на Ваш нынешний вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

<<**ЛЯСЫ**>> - смотрим  **"Полный церковно-славянский словарь"** магистра Гр. Дьяченко , стр. 1040 (в прибавлениях к Л) /интернет-ссылка [Лясы ПЦСС - лясы.](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_1040.htm)/ : **Лясы = болтовня , балясы , росказни ; "распускать лясы" - болтать что-нибудь , лгать .** Скриншот смотрите ниже . <<**ТОЧИТЬ**>> по тому же ПЦСС , на стр. 728 /интернет-ссылка [ПЦСС - точу](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0728.htm) / : <<ИЗЛИВАТЬ / ИСПУСКАТЬ / ИСТОЧНИК>> . Скриншот также см. ниже .                                         [image: ЛЯСЫ - ПЦСС] =========================================================================== [image: ТОЧУ - ПЦСС]

Answer (score 0):

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8B):

> Лясы (балясы) — это точеные фигурные столбики перил у крылечка;
>   изготовить такую красоту мог только настоящий мастер. Наверное,
>   сначала «точить балясы» означало вести изящную, причудливую,
>   витиеватую (как балясы) беседу. А умельцев вести такую беседу к нашему
>   времени становилось меньше и меньше. Вот и стало это выражение
>   обозначать пустую болтовню.